# PHP post data is not working with AWS4 Signature method for authentication

Tags: php, authentication, post, aws4c

in the below example, when i am enabling post data `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);`
getting '**The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method**', but when i disabled the post data, its working.
Should i pass this data parameters anywhere else?

```
$get_token = new GetToken();
$token_obj = $get_token->get_session_token();

$accessKeyID = $token_obj->access_key_id;
$secretAccessKey = $token_obj->secret_key;
$regionName = $token_obj->region;
$serviceName = 'execute-api';
$httpMethodName = 'POST';
$canonicalURI = '/orders/salesorder';
$queryParametes = array();
$awsHeaders = array('content-type'=>'application/json','host'=>'api.mysite.com','id_token'=>$token_obj->id_token,'x-amz-date'=>gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z"),'x-amz-security-token'=>$token_obj->session_token);
$payload = "";

$get_aws4_sign = new AWSV4($accessKeyID,$secretAccessKey,$regionName,$serviceName,$httpMethodName,$canonicalURI,$queryParametes,$awsHeaders,$payload);
$headers_result = $get_aws4_sign->getHeaders();

$headersArr = array(
    'host' => $headers_result['host'],
    'id_token' => $headers_result['id_token'],
    'xamzdate' => $headers_result['x-amz-date'],
    'xamzsecuritytoken' => $headers_result['x-amz-security-token'],
    'Authorization' => $headers_result['Authorization']
);

$data = array("id" => "126757879");
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('https://api.mysite.com/orders/salesorder');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
   'content-type: '.$headers_result['content-type'],
   'host: '.$headers_result['host'],
   'id_token: '.$headers_result['id_token'],
   'x-amz-date: '.$headers_result['x-amz-date'],
   'x-amz-security-token: '.$headers_result['x-amz-security-token'],
   'Authorization: '.$headers_result['Authorization']
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

//execute post
$result = json_decode( curl_exec($ch), TRUE);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: What does curl_error return?

Comment: I'm getting 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method' when I enabled CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, but when i'm disabled that line, it works

Comment: Isn't this because you create the signature in line 14 based on the empty payload from line 12 and add data after the signing in line 33? Shouldn't you set $payload to your $data_string before the calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$get_token = new GetToken();
$token_obj = $get_token->get_session_token();

$accessKeyID = $token_obj->access_key_id;
$secretAccessKey = $token_obj->secret_key;
$regionName = $token_obj->region;
$serviceName = 'execute-api';
$httpMethodName = 'POST';
$canonicalURI = '/orders/salesorder';
$queryParametes = array();
$awsHeaders = array('content-type'=>'application/json','host'=>'api.mysite.com','id_token'=>$token_obj->id_token,'x-amz-date'=>gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z"),'x-amz-security-token'=>$token_obj->session_token);

$data = array("id" => "126757879");
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$payload = $data_string;

$get_aws4_sign = new AWSV4($accessKeyID,$secretAccessKey,$regionName,$serviceName,$httpMethodName,$canonicalURI,$queryParametes,$awsHeaders,$payload);
$headers_result = $get_aws4_sign->getHeaders();

$headersArr = array(
    'host' => $headers_result['host'],
    'id_token' => $headers_result['id_token'],
    'xamzdate' => $headers_result['x-amz-date'],
    'xamzsecuritytoken' => $headers_result['x-amz-security-token'],
    'Authorization' => $headers_result['Authorization']
);

$ch = curl_init('https://api.mysite.com/orders/salesorder');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
   'content-type: '.$headers_result['content-type'],
   'host: '.$headers_result['host'],
   'id_token: '.$headers_result['id_token'],
   'x-amz-date: '.$headers_result['x-amz-date'],
   'x-amz-security-token: '.$headers_result['x-amz-security-token'],
   'Authorization: '.$headers_result['Authorization']
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

//execute post
$result = json_decode( curl_exec($ch), TRUE);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);
```